# Route [X.store] not defined :S

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm doing a simple form to send data to DB and when I submit it it appears the title error.

I think I defined everything perfect, but I can't understand where I'm failing.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
> Route [EnviarCurriculum.store] not defined. (View: C:\laragon\www\envio-curriculum\resources\views\enviar_curriculum.blade.php)

`web.php`

```
<?php

Route::resource('/', 'enviarCurriculum\EnviarCurriculumController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store']);
```

`EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use app\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;


class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view ('enviar_curriculum');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view ('enviar_curriculum', ['post' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function store(StoreEnviarCurriculumPost $request)
    {
        EnviarCurriculum::create($request->validated());

        return back() -> with('status', '¡Post creado con éxito!');
    }
}
```

`enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{{ route("EnviarCurriculum.store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf

        <h4>Datos Personales</h4>    
        <small class="pull-right">sin espacios, ni guiones</small>
        <br>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="frmInscripcionEmpleoNIF" class="form-control" placeholder="* NIF/NIE/Pasaporte" maxlength="20" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input autocomplete="nope" type="text" id="frmInscripcionEmpleoNombre" class="form-control" placeholder="* Nombre" maxlength="50" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="frmInscripcionEmpleoApellido1" class="form-control" placeholder="* 1º Apellido" maxlength="50" required data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <input autocomplete="off" type="text" id="frmInscripcionEmpleoApellido2" class="form-control" placeholder="2º Apellido" maxlength="50" data-error="Por favor rellene este campo">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        <select class="form-control" name="frmInscripcionEmpleoSexo" required id="frmInscripcionEmpleoSexo">
            <option disabled selected value="">* Sexo</option>
            <option value="H">Hombre</option>
            <option value="M">Mujer</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your route in `web.php`

```
Route::resource('/', 'enviarCurriculum\EnviarCurriculumController')->only(['index', 'create', 'store'])->name('EnviarCurriculum');
```

Comment: Thanks pal!!!

I cant vote you +1 until I've 15 rep, but thanks ;)